# Getting multiple LastInserted IDs in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

Instead of inserting a new query for every item I decided to change my code to do a batch job with would reduce the amount of time it would take to insert all of the new items.

Once I had finished this I noticed that I need the last ID inserted for the new GameItem class instance for it's ID, how can I work around this?

```
public static List<GameItem> CreateMultipleItems(ItemData data, PlayerData playerData, string ExtraData, int Amount, int GroupId = 0)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Data cannot be null.");
    }

    var items = new List<GameItem>();

    using (var dbConnection = Program.Server.DatabaseHandler.Connection)
    {
        var queries = new List<string> {"INSERT INTO `habbo_items` (base_item,user_id,room_id,x,y,z,wall_pos,rot,extra_data) VALUES "};

        for (var i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
        {
            queries.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", 
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString(data.Id.ToString()), 
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString(playerData.Id.ToString()),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString("0"),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString("0"),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString("0"),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString("0"),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString(""),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString("0"),
                MySqlHelper.EscapeString(ExtraData)
            ) + ",");

            var item = new GameItem(Convert.ToInt32(dbConnection.GetLastId()), 0, data.Id, ExtraData, 0, 0, 0, 0, playerData.Id, GroupId, 0, 0, "");

            if (GroupId > 0)
            {
                dbConnection.SetQuery("INSERT INTO `habbo_items_groups` (`id`, `group_id`) VALUES (@id, @gid)");
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("id", item.Id);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("gid", GroupId);
                dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            items.Add(item);
        }

        dbConnection.SetBatch(queries);
        dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Purpose you can push ado.net DataTable for inserting in sql server.

### Step-1

Create custom table value data type in sql server.

### Step-2

Create stored procedure with your custom data type parameter and return identity column value from output parameter.

in sql server

> **@@identity**

return last inserted identity column value

### Step-3

Create datatable and fill this datatable and set parameter value from this datatable and send to sql server for insertion operation

**Note: table value type support Sql Server 2008 onward**.

Comment: You haven't shown any code example on how to do this and your steps are unclear..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[habbo_items](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[base_item] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[user_id] [int] NULL,
[room_id] [int] NOT NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_habbo_items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

```
create procedure sp_save(@habbo_items_TBL habbo_items_TBL readonly, @result int output)
```

as
    insert into habbo_items(base_item,user_id,room_id)
                select base_item,user_id,room_id from @habbo_items_TBL
    set @result=@@IDENTITY
go

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("habbo_items_TBL");
    dt.Columns.Add("base_item", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("user_id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("room_id", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add("base item1", 1, 2);
    dt.Rows.Add("base item2", 1, 2);
    dt.Rows.Add("base item3", 2, 3);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_save", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@habbo_items_TBL", dt);

    SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
    outPutParameter.ParameterName = "@result";
    outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
    outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Int32 result = Convert.ToInt32(outPutParameter.Value);
```